# What is the proof of Tawheed?

Tags: tawheed

I’m Christian and want to convert but I haven’t seen any firm proofs of tawheed.

The Quran has two arguments but I am not convinced by them.not because they’re wrong but because I need more analysis of these arguments.

Any arguments from kalam?

Comment: Could you quote the *"Quran has two arguments"*.

Answer (score -1):

I will try my best to answer your question.

1. Is there more than one god?
   Well we know this is impossible as it says in the quran
   “Had there been therein (in the heavens and the earth) alihah (gods) besides Allah, then verily both would have been ruined. Glorified be Allah, the Lord of the Throne, (High is He) above all that (evil) they associate with Him!” Quran (Surah Al-Anbiya, 22)
   there would have been so much confusion in  the world and fights one of the "gods" prevailing over the other  the other "gods" wanting power and so on there would be no harmony and even if there was harmony it would eventually vanquish due to jealousy and impatient from the other "gods"  just as we see friends who's relationship are strong for years than suddenly their friendship crumbles and fight happens.
2. is there a god or is there no god?

Ask yourself this brother did the universe come randomly by complete chance so we are talking about the sun, stars, moon, ocean, etc? or did the universe create itself? or did the universe come into existence by a creator? I and many others know the first two questions is that is impossible for the universe to have come by chance due the perfect wonders of our solar system and everything else in our universe to have come by chance that's like saying is impossible for a robot to have come by chance everyone knows a robot has a creator, so why not the universe which is more complex than a robot? me and many others know having more than one god would be impossiblen for example one of the gods could have a different opinion to the other how would the conflicts resolve if this is continously, can there really be more than 2 supremes?

"Allah sets forth the parable of a slave owned by several quarrelsome masters, and a slave owned by only one master. Are they equal in condition?1 Praise be to Allah! In fact, most of them do not know." (Quran)
The last question is the correct answer that there is a creator who has given to each thing that which is suited to it and will guarantee for their on going function, such as the heart, veins, chromosomes and the list can go on and on. Can a green plant live without oxygen? no they are dependant on it so what happens when there is no oxygen supplies for the green plants? they simply won't survive
If you ponder all things you will find that they are dependent upon Allah. Were it not for Allah, nothing would remain.